# Double integrals of function involving 3 variables

Tags: matlab

Suppose the function of 3 variables is `F(T,x,y)=ln(T-x)exp(T+y^3)`, I want to compute things like

`H(T)=\int_0^T \int_0^x ln(T-x)exp(T+y^3) dy dx`

What I want is that for different values of T, say 0:0.25:2, I can obtain H(0:0.25:2) immediately. The code I used is as follow:

```
fun=@(T,x,y) ln(T-x)exp(T+y^3)
ymax=@(x)x
H=@(T)arrayfun(@(s)integral2(fun,0,s,0,ymax),T)
```

But it doesn't work. Matlab gives error. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, natural log is not `ln()`, but `log()`.

First of all,change your function as below pattern.

```
fun=@(x,y) log(T-x).*exp(T+y.^3)
```

Here, I used an operator `*` for product, and added `.` in front of `*` and `^` in order to describe matrix product.

One example is below, for getting integral according to T.

```
T=0:0.25:5;

N=length(T);

all_H=zeros(1,N);

s=2;

for k=1:N;

    fun=@(x,y) log(T(k)-x).*exp(T(k)+y.^3)
    ymax=@(x)x
    H=integral2(fun,0,s,0,ymax)

    all_H(k)=H;

end

plot(abs(all_H))
```

Comment: Is it possible to write without for loop? like if we define f=@(t) t.^2, f([0,1,2]) can be computed without the use of for loop.

Comment: I think if you don't want to use for loop, `integral2` function is not proper.

Comment: The use of integral2 is not a must, if it is not restricted, is it still possible to reduce the problem to my goal, i.e. no for loop is used?

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help for the solution. Without your solution, I think I am still spending much time to solve the problem.